# Calling View in API Request Factory when testing in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Whenever we test an API in Django Rest Framework using API Request Factory why do we call the view when we are already passing the url .
Look at the following code for better understanding .

```
request = self.factory.post("/api/v1/menu/", data)
views = MenuResource.as_view({"post": "post"})
response = views(request)
response.render()
self.assertEqual(201, response.status_code)
```

In  the above code we are calling the url as well as calling the view . View is being called for rendering the view on the url but that is not what my use case is . I just want to test the response code . Is there a way of getting the response code without rendering the view as that is an over kill for my use case .

I have looked for other methods except for using API Request Factory but i just wanted to know why does API Request Factory need to call the view . Is there any advantage in comparison to other API Testing modules present in Django Rest Framework.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are not making a request to the URL.

`request = self.factory.post("/api/v1/menu/", data)` simply creates a request object for you to use it does not actually make the request.

So testing the view in your case consists of creating a request object and passing it to the view which mimics the way an actual request would be passed and processed by that view.

If you want to send actual request you need to mock a test server which will handle the actual requests.

Comment: So why do we need to do that . Why even create an object when we can actually call a request instead of creating an object .

Comment: With a created request object you don't need to mock a test server and avoid that dependency. For unit tests you don't/shouldn't care about a test server mock, only the function that is execute.